# Изображения в Opencart очень сильно грузят сайт

Tags: php, база-данных, opencart

Недавно встала задача, импортировать большой каталог товаров в магазин opencart. Товаров более 100 000. Картинки к этим товарам находятся на удаленном ресурсе.
1) Я импортировал все товары через Export and Import Tool V3.x (multilingual).
2) Добавил модификатор "Download Remote Image" для отображения картинок с удаленного ресурса.
Картинки работают, все хорошо, однако сайт грузится по 1-3 минуты. Как можно вылечить? Понятное дело что товаров очень много, картинок тоже и сайт не справляется, но должно же быть решение. Хостинг мне ответил, что тариф у меня норм, всего хватает и косяк в большой бд. (предложили перейти на vds, не думаю что это истинно правильное решение). 
Грузит сайт именно модификатор, хотя на локалке все работало отлично.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отдельным процессом по крону закачиваете с требуемой регулярностью на свой сервер/хостинг картинки и обращаетесь уже к сохраненному.

При этом решении Вы сможете, в авторежиме, организовать и оптимизацию/сжатие картинок, что приведет к еще большему ускорению работы ресурса.

Можно попробовать и неизменять указанные уже адреса, а по маске в htaccess или через php перенаправить на ваше закаченное хранилище.

Можно и вариант - проверяется доступность удаленного ресурса в разумное/указанное время - и если нет, то обращение к локальному хранилищу.

Или наоборот - при отсуствии в локальном нужного файла обращение к удаленному.

Comment: Спасибо, становится яснее! Единственная проблема это составить запрос по крону. Я с этим очень слабо знаком. Не могли бы вы помочь, с написанием запроса?

Comment: Пожалуйста) Смотрите - нужно написатиь скрипт, который бы копировал все с удаленного - например, папку с картинками в какое-то место на вашем сервере/хостинге. Затем, установив оптимальное время/периодичность обновления на удаленном ресурсе и необходимость закачки, сформировать крон-задачу для запуска этого скрипта. Скрипт может быть любой, - php, cgi и прочее - чтоб он решал поставленную задачу скачки. Ну, а саму строку на крон составить можно будет, когда все остальное известно - это самое простое... кстати, в скроипте можно проверять на наличие уже имеющегося, чтоб не закачивать лишний раз.

Comment: Простите! Забыл написать, что вы были правы! Я так и сделал. Только не через крон. Написал скрипт, на локалке. Там убрал лимит по времени и скачал все картинки! Потом просто перекинул на хост! Заняло примерно пол суток!